# How to load php file using ajax. Some Compatibility Problem

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax, cross-browser

I try to load a php file called summary.template.hp when the content in class profi is clicked and 
load changepass.template.php when the content of class changepass is clicked.

There is no problem in loading in firefox. But in Internet Explorer 7 the summary.template.php file is loading but the changepass.template.php file is not loading. Give me some solution. Whether i have to unload the previous page before loading the next page?. If yes, then give me some tips for unloading the page.

```
$(function() {
  $(".profi").click(function() {
    $(".block1").load("views/summary.template.php");
     return false;
  });
});


 $(function() {
  $(".changepass").click(function() {
    $(".block1").load("views/changepass.template.php");
    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ColdFusion developer noted a somewhat similar situation here:
[jQuery .load() function + IE + dynamic URL = hair loss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023442/jquery-load-function-ie-dynamic-url-hair-loss) -- so, is it possible that changepass.template.php script is returning headers or other code that causes IE to fail? Check the exact server response that's generated from changepass.template.php in Firebug.

About this?

> Whether i have to unload the previous
>   page before loading the next page?

Does the changepass link work in IE if you click it first?

It shouldn't really be necessary but since IE can be unpredictable, you might try:

```
$(".block1").empty().load("views/changepass.template.php");
```